# How to find intersection points between two circles?

Tags: php

We have two points (centers of two circles) and their radius in meters, those radius make the circle. We need to find intersection points. For example we have  lat1 = 55.685025, lng1 = 21.118995, r1 = 150 and lat2 = 55.682393, lng2 = 21.121387, r2 = 250. Below you can find our current formula:

```
// Find a and h.
$a = ($circle_1_r * $circle_1_r - $circle_2_r * $circle_2_r + $distance * $distance) / (2 * $distance);
$h = sqrt($circle_1_r * $circle_1_r - $a * $a);

// Find P2.
$circle_3_x = $circle_1_x + $a * ($circle_2_x - $circle_1_x) / $distance;
$circle_3_y = $circle_1_y + $a * ($circle_2_y - $circle_1_y) / $distance;

// Get the points P3.
$intersection_1 = $this->newLatLngPoint(
    ($circle_3_x + $h * ($circle_2_y - $circle_1_y) / $distance),
    ($circle_3_y - $h * ($circle_2_x - $circle_1_x) / $distance)
);

$intersection_2 = $this->newLatLngPoint(
    ($circle_3_x - $h * ($circle_2_y - $circle_1_y) / $distance),
    ($circle_3_y + $h * ($circle_2_x - $circle_1_x) / $distance)
);
```

We find such intersection points (yellow markers), however those locations doesn't match in real world.

[image]

Someone, can help to find where the problem is and how to sort it ?

P.S.
Does the altitude (Height above mean sea level) affect the final result? I don't use it but may be should?

Comment: You may want to try at http://math.stackexchange.com/ for the algorithm, from which it shouldn't be a problem to program it in any language ;-)

Comment: Are the X and Y variable corredpond to latitude and longitude? You can't do math with latitude and longitude coordinate, a sphere is not a plan. For example, the distance between two points is not sqrt((x1-x2)^2 + (y1-y2)^2). See http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html for example.